# git log shows branches in sequential order instead of parallel

Tags: git

I cloned the repo from bitbucket. Then I added the remote heroku branch:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:heroku-repo.git
```

Now then I call `git log` to show all the branches:

```
git log --graph --all --pretty=bla-bla-bla
```

It shows to me all commits from the heroku remote and then all commits from the master branch in one row:
[image]

On the picture `37b03ff — init` is the first commit on the heroku (5 months ago).

**Why it shows after the last commit on the master branch (23 hours ago)?**

BTW, if I open this repo in the Tower app it shows branches in parallel, as expected.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default, the commits are shown in reverse chronological order.

--date-order

Show no parents before all of its children are shown, but otherwise show commits in the commit timestamp order.

form https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html

Comment: `--date-order` makes `git log` output the same as in the second screenshot. Seems that it solves the problem. But I don't quite understand why `git log` didn't show all commits from all branches in the chronological order by default?

Answer (score 0):

First, your remote heroku and origin seems 2 totally different repo, so their history/log are simple added, but in different column like your 2nd screenshot.

Second, according 2nd screenshot, heroku/HEAD seems 'newer' than origin/HEAD, so by time decent order, it will display first.

Third, I try to explain your 1st screenshot, heroku/HEAD is newer, so it'll display before origin/HEAD, also, in different **column**. But the screenshot seems like they are on same column, maybe:

1. all of heroku history ends, so origin history comes up in same column
2. pretty format, try `git log --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline --graph --decorate` or `git log --graph --pretty=format:"%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%ar) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset" --abbrev-commit`